# Does this class stay created?

Tags: c#, class, timer, dynamic-assemblies

I'm dynamically loading an assembly, creating an instance of a class that implements `IRegisterable`, then calling a registration method with this shortened code:

```
    public bool RegisterASM(string path)
    {
        Assembly asm = LoadAssembly(path); //helper to load assembly

        if (asm != null)
        {
            var registerableTypes = from t in asm.GetTypes()
                                    where t.IsClass &&
                                    (t.GetInterface("IRegisterable") != null)
                                    select t;

            foreach (Type t in registerableTypes)
            {
                IRegisterable reg = (IRegisterable)asm.CreateInstance(t.FullName, true);
                reg.Register(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assembly not found");
            return false;
        }
   }
```

And an example of the `IRegisterable` class:

```
public class Class1 : IRegisterable
{

    public bool Register(IRegistrationUtilities regHandler)
    {
        Action<Dictionary<string, object>> actionMeathod = TestJob;
        regHandler.RegisterJob(actionMeathod, "Testing", 30000, true);

        Class3 c = new Class3();
        actionMeathod = c.TestJob3;
        regHandler.RegisterJob(actionMeathod, "Test3", 5000, true);
        return true;
    }

    public void TestJob(Dictionary<string, object> vars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SleepStart");
        Thread.Sleep(40000);
        Console.WriteLine("SleepEnd");
    }
}

public class Class3
{
    int t = 5;

    public void TestJob3(Dictionary<string, object> vars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test 3...{0}", t);
    }
}
```

When the class registers, it calls a method in the `RegistrationHandler` that will in turn call a method in the `JobScheduler` that will create a `Threading.Timer` with the `TimerCallback` being the `actionMeathod` passed in the registration. Besides that, there is no other reference to the `IRegisterable` class.

My question is, does the class stay in memory since there is a reference to the method or is the class recreated every time the method is called? Or a combination of both?

The reason I ask is that `Class1.Register` creates an instance of `Class3` and passes `Class3.TestJob3` as the `actionMeathod`. When `Class3` is created, it sets `t=5`, which is used in `TestJob3`. but when the `Register` method exits, the instance of `Class3` is destroyed since it was a local variable. But the timed call to `Class3.TestJob3` still has `t=5`, so is `Class3` recreated every time or does it persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when the `Register` method exits, the instance of `Class3` is destroyed since it was a local variable.

This is incorrect for reference types.  Reference objects are allocated on the heap.  The local variable `c` merely *points to* this object.  The garbage collector will destroy the instance at a later time when it determines that the object is not referenced.

However, the delegate object (`Action<Dictionary<string, object>>`) has a reference to the `Class3` object, so it will not be garbage collected until that delegate object itself can be collected.  So the `Class3` instance will indeed outlive execution of the `Register()` method, since it will still be referenced by the delegate after this method returns.

You can prove this to yourself:

```
Class3 c = new Class3();
actionMeathod = c.TestJob3;
regHandler.RegisterJob(actionMeathod, "Test3", 5000, true);

// Add this line.
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(c, actionMeathod.Target));
```

The output will be "True", indicating that the delegate does indeed have a reference to the same object that `c` does.

Comment: That makes sense, I always forget about the different types of variables. If the class was designated as `static`, obviously the class would never be created but variables stored in the static class would persist correct?

Comment: @JRLambert Correct, and if you take a delegate to a static method, the delegate's `Target` property is actually `null` (since the method doesn't belong to an object instance).  If you take a delegate to a method of a struct (a value type), then the struct is boxed and stored as the delegate target.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on implementation of your `IRegistrationUtilities.RegisterJob` method. For example, if it puts your `TestJob`'s action into a private variable, your `Class3` will stay alive until `IRegistrationUtilities` instance is not disposed by the garbage collector.

Also please be aware that even if `RegisterJob` does nothing, your `Class3` may not be disposed immediately(or even have same length of life as your application) because of nondeterministic nature of the .NET garbage collector.

Comment: I understand the non-immediate nature of the `GC`, I'm just worried about memory bloat.

Comment: @JRLambert, Then focus on how `IRegistrationUtilities` stores and releases registered jobs.